# Assign value to entire group based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, equality

I'm new to all this, so sorry in advance:

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   Issuance Issue Date  Date        Spread
1   1       12/31/2018  12/31/2018   3.42 
2   1       12/31/2018  1/31/2019    3.45 
3   1       12/31/2018  2/28/2019    3.49 
4   1       12/31/2018  3/31/2019    3.52 
5   1       12/31/2018  4/30/2019    3.56 
6   1       12/31/2018  5/31/2019    3.59 
7   2       3/31/2019   3/31/2019    3.52 
8   2       3/31/2019   4/30/2019    3.56 
9   2       3/31/2019   5/31/2019    3.59
```

I have a list of issuances and spreads, and I want to make a new column 'fixed spread' to return the spread when the "Issue Date" equals the "Date" and remains fixed for all dates, like so:

```
  Issuance    Issue Date      Date     Spread   Fixed Spread
 1   1        12/31/2018    12/31/2018   3.42    3.42 
 2   1        12/31/2018    1/31/2019    3.45    3.42 
 3   1        12/31/2018    2/28/2019    3.49    3.42 
 4   1        12/31/2018    3/31/2019    3.52    3.42 
 5   1        12/31/2018    4/30/2019    3.56    3.42 
 6   1        12/31/2018    5/31/2019    3.59    3.42 
 7   2        3/31/2019     3/31/2019    3.52    3.52 
 8   2        3/31/2019     4/30/2019    3.56    3.52 
 9   2        3/31/2019     5/31/2019    3.59    3.52
```

i've gotten pretty close with this:

```
df['fixed_spread'] = df.loc[df['Issue Date'].idxmin(), 'spread']
```

This does what i want at first, but it only looks at the first issuance for the whole dataframe (so the 'fixed spread' column would remain at 3.42 for all rows in the df example above).

Any suggestions on achieving what I want?

Comment: `3/31/2018  != 3/31/2019` and yet the fixed spread has been set for that row. Can you check that please?

Comment: sorry about that! the second issuance date in my actual df is 3/31/2019

Comment: Can you fix your data please so I can copy it into an answer?

Comment: yes - done! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `where` + `ffill` should do it.

```
df['Fixed Spread'] =  df.Spread.where(df['Issue Date'] == df['Date']).ffill()
```

Or,

```
df['Fixed Spread'] =  df.Spread.mask(df['Issue Date'] != df['Date']).ffill()
```

```
df

   Issuance  Issue Date        Date  Spread  Fixed Spread
1         1  12/31/2018  12/31/2018    3.42          3.42
2         1  12/31/2018   1/31/2019    3.45          3.42
3         1  12/31/2018   2/28/2019    3.49          3.42
4         1  12/31/2018   3/31/2019    3.52          3.42
5         1  12/31/2018   4/30/2019    3.56          3.42
6         1  12/31/2018   5/31/2019    3.59          3.42
7         2   3/31/2019   3/31/2019    3.52          3.52
8         2   3/31/2019   4/30/2019    3.56          3.52
9         2   3/31/2019   5/31/2019    3.59          3.52
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just create a temporary dataframe with just the rows where Issue Date equals Date and then join it with the first dataframe based on the Issuance key.

```
tmp_df = df[df['Issue Date']==df['Date']][['Issuance','Spread']]
tmp_df.columns = ['Issuance','Fixed Spread']
df = pd.merge(df,tmp_df,how='left',on='Issuance')
```

probably not optimal but it should work.

Comment: A merge is overkill here.